# how to remove garbage after printing alphabet?

Tags: assembly, nasm

i want  this code to print only 'B' but it prints some garbage after 'B', how to remove garbage? I am using NASM.

```
SECTION .data  
num: db "" , '$' ; reserves 1 byte in memory
SECTION .text
org 0 x100 ; assembler directive
mov ax , 33 ; this is recommended number representation
mov cx , 33 ; works smooth , but not recommended
add ax , cx
mov [num] , al ; saves result to memory
mov dx , num
mov ah , 0x9 ; system interrupt
int 0x21 ; system interrupt for printing
mov ah , 0x4c ; last two lines are
int 0x21 ; synonymous to return 0;
```

Comment: Try `num: db 0 , '$'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mov dl, 'B';
mov ah, 2h;
int 21h;
```

int21 function 2h displays the byte in dl as a char on the console.